# Is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx|x\rangle \langle x|x= \hat{x}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Does $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \!dx|x\rangle \langle x|x= \hat{x}$, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx |x\rangle\langle x| = \mathbb{1}$? If not, why not?

Comment: You're right that $\int dx|x\rangle \langle x|x= x$, but it is not because you can just replace that integral with 1. Like with an ordinary integral you can't just solve a part of the integral, you have to consider the whole thing at once: $\int f(x) g(x)dx \neq g(x) \int f(x)dx$. To prove that this equality is true, you have to show that acting $x$ on any function does the same thing as acting $\int dx|x\rangle \langle x|x$ on that function. And for that, it suffices to show that the two operators do the same thing to any basis element, like in knzhou's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true that
$$\int dx \, |x \rangle \langle x | x = \hat{x} \tag{1}.$$
To prove this equation, it suffices to show that the operators on both sides of the equation act the same way on a basis. We know that
$$\hat{x} |x' \rangle = x' |x' \rangle \tag{2}.$$
Now act with the left-hand side on the same thing:
$$\int dx \, |x \rangle \langle x | x |x' \rangle = \int dx \, x | x \rangle \langle x | x' \rangle = \int dx \, x | x \rangle \delta(x - x') = x' |x' \rangle. \tag{3}$$
So acting with both sides of $(1)$ on $|x' \rangle$ gives $x' |x'\rangle$, and the $|x' \rangle$'s are a complete basis, so the two sides are equal.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please clarify what you mean by "both sides"?

Comment: @ChristinaDaniel Sure, I updated the answer.